# Apply conditional CSS to Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm struggling to apply a conditional Vue statement to change the CSS style based on the text value. I have tried following other tutorials with no luck as I'm a beginner with Vue.

If for example I want the class to be is-success when `{{s.specialType}} == "food"` AND is-danger when `{{s.specialType}} == "drink"` how would I do it.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

```
<div v-for="s in spc.specials" class="column is-one-third">
    <div class="field">
        <span class="tag is-success is-capitalized">{{s.specialType}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be achieved using `v-bind:class`

```
<span v-bind:class="{'is-success': s.specialType==='food', 'is-danger': s.specialType==='drink'}" class="tag is-capitalized">
  {{s.specialType}}
</span>
```

Ref: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google search for conditional rendering, i came up with the following solution:

```
<div v-for="s in spc.specials" class="column is-one-third">
<div class="field">
  <span class="tag is-success is-capitalized" v-if="s.specialType === 'food'">
    {{s.specialType}}
  </span>
  <span class="tag is-danger is-capitalized" v-else-if="s.specialType === 'drink'">
    {{s.specialType}}
  </span>
</div>
```

[Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Comment: Why play with rendering when Vue already has directives designed specifically for conditional class addition and removal?